# on magento, how can I redirect the page when the customer visits a certain product?

Tags: php, magento

My task is to make the user be redirected to a page when it enters a product' view.
I am wondering if magento has something builtin to do that. Does it?
if not, where is the correct place for me to code this?

Edit:
The customer is searching for a product, then it clicks some product, instead of going to the product view, I would like to redirect it to a specific page based on the product it clicked at.

thanks!

Comment: Are you just wanting to use your own template for the product page, or prevent them from viewing the product page? Can you give a concrete example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can manage redirects from catalog > url rewrite management